# Convert a decimal value to currency format without rounding the value

Tags: c#

I have 18.9954545454545454545454545 value and i need to convert it to currency format without rounding it.

```
18.9954545454545454545454545.ToString("c");
```

But returns me "$19.00" but i need "$18.99".

Is there any method to calculate this.

I have a method that gives me exactly what i need but don't think that method is good to implement.

```
@Convert.ToDecimal(18.9954545454545454545454545.Substring(0, 5)).ToString("c")
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you simply want to erase everything after the first 2 decimals, so 18.99999999 would become 18.99?

Comment: Do you think we can round off the total if we are working on some eCommerce project. Is it a good practice? @Simon

Comment: Or its fine to go with substring? @Simon

Comment: I am no expert in the financial world. I would personally ask my boss or someone higher up what to do with this. Do you want to round everything? What do we do with 18.995? It might be only 1 cent, but if that transaction is made a million times, it starts to make a difference.

Comment: Yes, That's what i am concerning about.

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but `ToString()` doesn't actually do any rounding in the value; it just gives the closest approximation as a String.

Comment: You could put `F` after `18.9954545454545454545454545F`, maybe this would work.

Comment: @UniCell that would just turn the `double` literal into a (single) `float`. You should always be using `decimal` when dealing with currency. You could turn the literal into a `decimal` by appending an `m`, but that doesn't solve this issue.